# I need to get the output of scraping in csv but I get only one result in csv

Tags: php, xpath, web-scraping, screen-scraping, fputcsv

```
$arr =array(
        ("link to scrape"),
        ("link to scrape")
        );
```

I'm using two links to scrape.

```
foreach($arr as $value){
    $html = file_get_contents($value);
    //get the html returned from the following url
    $pokemon_doc = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); //disable libxml errors
    if(!empty($html)){               //if any html is actually returned
            $pokemon_doc->loadHTML($html);
            libxml_clear_errors(); 

            $pokemon_xpath = new DOMXPath($pokemon_doc);
            $pokemon_row = $pokemon_xpath->query("//*[contains(@class, 'product-title')]/*[2]");

        if($pokemon_row->length > 0){ 
            foreach($pokemon_row as $row){      
                $list = $row->nodeValue ;
                echo $list; 
                $lists = explode(',',$list);//convert string to array       


            }
            echo "<a href='demosaved.csv' download>download</a>";
            $file = fopen('demosaved.csv', 'a');// create csv file
            foreach($lists as $line){     // store data in csv
                fputcsv($file, $line);
            }
            fclose($file);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using two links so I should get two results for each link but I get the result of the second link only.

Comment: Does `echo $list;` prints all the values of both links?

Comment: yes its show every category of each link